# MySQL - Convert MM/DD/YY to Unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

Is there an easy (single query) way to do this?

I'm reading those values from a column in a table and I think that the column itself is defined as a string (can't be helped, i'm afraid).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp);

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 10:30:19');
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(fieldName AS DATE));
```

Comment: Hmmm great but I should have mentioned i'm reading those values from a column in a table and I think that the column itself is defined as a string. My bad, sorry

Comment: @Hal: Yes because we have converted it to DATE

Comment: I suppose (haven't checked it) it assumes the format specified in the `%Y-%m-%d` variable (`SELECT @@date_format`). In my server it is `%Y-%m-%d`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('08/05/10','%m/%d/%y'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT '12/31/10',
    STR_TO_DATE('12/31/10', '%m/%d/%y'),
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('12/31/10', '%m/%d/%y'))
```

Both functions are covered here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html