# MySQL convert YYYY-MM-DD to unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

I want to convert a YYYY-MM-DD column to unix timestamp. Similar to this question: [MySQL - Convert MM/DD/YY to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413559/mysql-convert-mm-dd-yy-to-unix-timestamp)

MySQL does not seem to transform a value of '2012-05-10' to the correct unixtime. Here is the suggested function that fails:
`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(dateid AS DATE)) AS unixtime`

Comment: What is the expected result? What are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of `MySQL` you are using? As tested by MySQL 5.5.27 in SQLFiddle these two queries worked

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST('2012-05-10 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)) As UnixTime;
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST('2012-05-10' AS DATE))  As UnixTime;
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2301)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem you are having exactly, but the following works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE ex (dt VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO ex SET dt = '2012-05-10';

SELECT
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-05-10') ex1,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt)  ex2,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST('2012-05-10' AS DATE)) ex3,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(dt AS DATE)) ex4
FROM ex;
```

returns:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ex1        | ex2        | ex3        | ex4        |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 1336633200 | 1336633200 | 1336633200 | 1336633200 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

As you can see, there is no need to `CAST()` if the string is in the form `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, as MySQL implicitly converts strings in this format to `DATE`s.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a215/3