# How do you convert a string to a date in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I must be doing something wrong.  I'm trying to search the database on a OrderDate column which is stored as a string ex. "7/21/2016 9:13:31 PM"
AND I want to convert OrderDate to a unix timestamp for the query statement :

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(OrderDate,  '%e/%c/%Y %r')) >= 
'1471496400' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(OrderDate, '%e/%c/%Y
%r')) <= '1471669199'
```

There are plenty of results in the table that should match this. But I'm not getting any of them. What am I doing wrong?

I've read the manual and searched the internet and cannot figure out what I am doing so please don't tell me to RTM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Convert MM/DD/YY to Unix timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413559/mysql-convert-mm-dd-yy-to-unix-timestamp)

Comment: 7/21/2016 9:13:31 PM is a value in OrderDate, don't get how to convert it to timestamp

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(OrderDate, '%c/%e/%Y')) >= '$timestamp1'
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(OrderDate, '%c/%e/%Y')) <= '$timestamp2'
```